# @media not working below 980px width

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to add full responsiveness to my website. But, for some reason, it won't read parts below 980px of width. Here's my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1029px){
    h1{
        font-size: 75px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:980px){
    h1{
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:954px){
    h1{
        font-size: 65px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

The 980px part is the last that can be read, if I change it to 979px it stops reading it, as if it wasn't there. `!important` doesn't change anything. What can I do? Why is there a magical barrier of 980px?

Comment: What do you see in the inspector / dev tools?

Comment: @SLaks When I have e.g. 800px wide, it reads styles for max-width 1029 instead of second or third one.

Comment: How have you set your meta viewport tag?

Comment: Works here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ptqyywq/). Maybe you have some styles overriding your queries. What do you see when you inspect the elements?

Comment: @karthick <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @HunterTurner as I said to SLack, I see that it uses the last style set that was dedicated for widths over 980px, even if its far below 980px and omits 2 or 3 style sets.

Comment: Did you try with media only screen and (min-width: 955px) and (max-width: 979px) and media only screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1029px) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should realigned your media, it will be work for you may be.

I make a fiddle and it's working as you want with `media query`

**[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hea7ka2r/2/)**

```
@media screen and (max-width:954px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 65px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1029px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 75px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:980px) {
    h1 {
      font-size: 70px;
    }
    h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it gives totally opposite effect - it doesn't read the small width style sets, but also gets not appropiate styles for bigger widths - because all of them are eventually ending on the last set.

Comment: Wow, the second option, nesting `@media` inside another `@media`, seems to have worked fine for me! Thank you!

Comment: it's my pleasure..  :)

Comment: nesting them doesn't seem to work for me, I have two files and both of them link the same main.css which has the `@media`, for one file it works but for the other everything except the `@media` is activated, and if I edit the main.css file using inspect to set the `@media` to 980px or more it works, and it appears in the style section of the changed element in inspect.EDIT:I don't know how did I not see the other answer but the other answer worked for me, the file that was working did have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` and the file that wasn't didn't

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you got `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` in `<head>` element